# Is the phrase "...no longer" being properly used in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> And the even stronger feeling of detachment upon reaching mine **no
>   longer knowing who I was.**

Is this use of "no longer" grammatical? Should I add a comma before *no*?

Comment: Why the question? What exactly makes you suspect if the expression is correct or maybe incorrect? Have you looked up 'no longer' in a dictionary?

Comment: @Kris I thought it sounded strange. I think the problem was because I didn't put a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the usage of the word is correct. And you need to add a comma before *no.*

> I felt a strong feeling of detachment upon reaching my home, no longer knowing who I was.

And as a matter of fact, you can remove the word *no longer* and it will still make sense:

> I felt a strong feeling of detachment upon reaching my home, knowing who I was.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't knowing who I was the opposite of no longer/not knowing who I was?

Comment: Sorry, I think my example is confusing. I updated the question with the original sentence.

Comment: Correct. It was trivial, my point was that even without _no longer_ your sentence would still be valid. (Though of course with different meanings)

Comment: And yes, add a comma before no longer and you're all set.

Comment: -1 The question is about the expression *no longer*, not the comma.

Comment: @Kris, you might want to read the question again, he asked if the use of _no longer_ in the sentence is correct, and if he should add a comma before the word _no_. I answered yes, and he should add a comma before no. But I guess my answer was a bit unclear so I'll revise it a bit.

Comment: 1. Comma use is, strictly speaking, not a grammar issue. 2. The title and the first sentence of the body of the question relate to the **grammaticality** of the expression *no longer*. The comma issue seems to have come as a 'suggested correction' or an after thought. **3.** Proof-reading is off topic on ELU. 4. The tag is 'grammaticality'.

Comment: The title asked if the usage is proper, and I don't think my answer is incorrect. As for proof-reading, I didn't think that this was proof-reading, if this was considered proof-reading, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Kris, he didn't ask whether the comma was grammatical or not, only whether “no longer” is. This answer gives a correct answer to that question. The title does not mention grammaticality at all. And whether the comma issue was an afterthought or not is entirely your interpretation. Tags do not necessarily represent the full range of issues being asked about. I would consider downvoting this answer to be abuse of the voting system.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: @Kris: Janus only wrote one comment. That is ***not*** an extended discussion under any definition of the word *extended*.

Comment: @PeterShor  Sir, "Extend" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/extend (And what I am doing now as well.)